# How to configure nginx.conf to accept URL at location directive?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

## Background

I am building an web app using nginx + gunicorn + Flask on Python. Here is the issue of configuring 'nginx.conf' and gunicorn service configuration file.

## What I want to do

The redirection the access for "http://example.com/" to http://127.0.0.1:8080 and the redirection the access for "http://example.com/login" to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login.

## Environment

- Platform: Amazon Lunux 2
- python v3.10.10
- gunicorn v21.2.0
- nginx v1.22.1

## Conf file

/etc/systemd/systemn/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/py
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/py/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/py/env/bin/gunicorn --config /path/to/config.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

configuration file for gunicorn

```
wsgi_app = "wsgi:app"
bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
workers = 2
daemon = True
```

nginx.conf file

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location = /login/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_added_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/login;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri @Flask;
    }
    location @Flask {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_added_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h2>Hello Index World</h2>"

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return "<h2>Login Page</h2>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

wsgi.py

```
from flask_app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

I checked the validity for 'nginx.conf' by executing 'sudo nginx -t' and obtained 'test is successful'. There are 2 location directives which configures proxy_pass. The one is redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8080 and the other is to http://127.0.0.1:8080/login.
In the gunicorn configuration file, the redirection is binded to port 8080.

## Result

When I accessed "http://example.com/", the response was:

**Method Now Allowed**

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

And when I accessed "http://example.com/login/", the response was:

**Not Found**

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Additionally, when I accessed "http://example.com/index.html", nginx welcome page was shown and when I accessed "http://example.com/login/index.html", corresponding page was shown.

## My Question

How do I describe location directives to realize what I want to do ?